# Earnings Quality for a large group of stocks

Tags: earnings

Does anyone have any recommendations for how to track earnings quality for a large number of stocks (500+) on a quarterly basis? I am familiar with the M-Score for detecting earnings manipulation but am wondering if anyone has any additional ideas that might lend themselves to a larger set of constituents. I would like to build out a model using capIQ data for this purpose. Thanks for your thoughts.